# How to format NullTime into human readable format like HH:MM:SS

Tags: json, go, methods, time, struct

I've managed to modify my code so it displays all table rows correctly, even if there are null values

```
type NullString struct {
    sql.NullString
}

func (ns *NullString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !ns.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(ns.String)
}

type LogItem struct {
    UserId           string     `form:"userid" json:"userid"`
    UserDate         string     `form:"date" json:"date"`
    CheckinTime      NullString `form:"checkintime" json:"checkintime"`
    CheckinLocation  NullString `form:"checkinlocation" json:"checkinlocation"`
    CheckoutTime     NullString `form:"checkouttime" json:"checkouttime"`
    CheckoutLocation NullString `form:"checkoutlocation" json:"checkoutlocation"`
}

db := DBconnect()
defer db.Close()

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM oc_log")
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
}

for rows.Next() {
    if err := rows.Scan(&logItem.UserId, &logItem.UserDate, &logItem.CheckinTime, &logItem.CheckinLocation, &logItem.CheckoutTime, &logItem.CheckoutLocation); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    } else {
        arrLogItem = append(arrLogItem, logItem)
    }
}
```

> {
>       "status": 200,
>       "message": "Success",
>       "Data": [
>           {
>               "userid": "9",
>               "date": "2019-09-25T00:00:00Z",
>               "checkintime": "0000-01-01T14:56:39+07:00",
>               "checkinlocation": "(100, 100)",
>               "checkouttime": "0000-01-01T15:52:22+07:00",
>               "checkoutlocation": "(100, 100)"
>           },
>           {
>               "userid": "10",
>               "date": "2019-09-27T00:00:00Z",
>               "checkintime": "0000-01-01T14:04:44+07:00",
>               "checkinlocation": "(123, 321)",
>               "checkouttime": null,
>               "checkoutlocation": null
>           }
>       ] }

Now the problem is how to format **0000-01-01T14:04:44+07:00** into human-friendlier output like **17:09:02**, for example?

This code doesn't compile:

```
func (ns *NullString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !ns.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(time.Parse(time.RFC3339, ns.String))
}
```

> too many arguments in call to json.Marshal
>           have (time.Time, error)
>           want (interface {})

Answer (score 0):

[`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) expects a single value, and [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) returns 2 values: the parsed time and an error. You have to handle that yourself and not pass it to `json.Marshal()`, for example:

```
func (ns *NullString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !ns.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, ns.String)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return json.Marshal(t.Format("15:04:05"))
}
```

Testing it:

```
ns := &NullString{}
data, err := json.Marshal(ns)
fmt.Println(string(data), err)

ns = &NullString{
    NullString: sql.NullString{
        String: time.Time{}.Add(time.Minute * 1029).Format(time.RFC3339),
        Valid:  true,
    },
}
data, err = json.Marshal(ns)
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-3nBSCgfWBG)):

```
null <nil>
"17:09:00" <nil>
```

Also be careful with the receiver type. You used pointer receivers (`ns *NullString`), yet you use your `NullString` as non-pointers in the `LogItem` struct. Which means when marshaling values of your `LogItem`, this `NullString.MarshalJSON()` will not be called. So instead use non-pointer receiver.

```
func (ns NullString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // ...
}
```